# eclipse проблемы с jquery

Tags: jquery, eclipse

Эклипс ругается на знак $. При использовании jquery.

Comment: пусть ругается. ты же не из под эклипса запускаешь.

Comment: ты его надеюсь в яваскрипте использушь

Comment: ну а где еще? оставлять eclipse недовольным не хочу, так как его капризы отвлекают

Comment: var j = jQuery.noConflict();  
И тогда вместо $(...) можно писать j(...) .

Comment: проблема с эклипсом а не с jquery, хотя все равно спасибо

Comment: Блин, ну как это пусть ругается? Зачем тогда вообще IDE использовть... давайте вообще в блокноте писать.. вы ведь не из него запускаете..

Comment: видимо тут никто эклипсом не пользуется

Answer (score 1):

Используйте альтернативный вызов 
$ меняйте на jquery

Comment: я хочу научить еклипс работать с общепринятым синтаксисом а не менять чтото в исходнике. Ведь ide неправильно работает!!

Comment: IDE работает правильно, оно просто не заточено под jQuery :( Лично я в Aptana Studio пишу скрипты и верстаю, понимает все что только можно :)